# RSA Algorithm: The length of the data to decrypt is not valid for the size of this key. in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

I am trying to decryption of a message.

Firstly I encrypted a message with RSA algorithm in C#.

You can think of it as a simple licensing application, I wrote a windows form application with the `RSAService` class below and I am doing the encryption operation here. I'm saving the result of the `Encrypt` method with a .txt file in a different project path. I save the result of the `GetPublicKey` method to the database.

```
    public class RSAService
{

    private static RSACryptoServiceProvider cryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
    private RSAParameters _privateKey;
    private RSAParameters _publicKey;


    public RSAService()
    {
        _privateKey = cryptoServiceProvider.ExportParameters(true);
        _publicKey = cryptoServiceProvider.ExportParameters(false);
    }

    public string GetPublicKey()
    {
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));

        xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, _publicKey);
        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }

    public string Encrypt(string plainText)
    {
        cryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        cryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters(_publicKey);

        var data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);
        var cypher = cryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt(data, false);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(cypher);
    }

}
```

Then, I need to decrypt this message, which I have encrypted in the main application where I saved the .txt file, and see its contents. There are parameters such as the number of users and usernames in the message content. But I can't decode the message. Below I share the methods I use for the solution.

```
   public class RSAService : IRSAService
{
    private static RSACryptoServiceProvider cryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
    private readonly ICompanyService _companyService;
    private RSAParameters _publicKey;



    public RSAService(ICompanyService companyService)
    {
        _companyService = companyService;
        _publicKey = cryptoServiceProvider.ExportParameters(false);
    }

    public string GetPublicKey(string companyCode) => _companyService.GetCompanyLicenceKey(companyCode);


    public string Decrypt(string cypherText, string companyCode)
    {
        using (cryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            var dataBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cypherText);
            var publicKeyText = GetPublicKey(companyCode);
            cryptoServiceProvider.**ImportParameters(????);**
            var plainText = cryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(dataBytes, false);
            return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plainText);
        }
    }

}
```

Here the question. I am reading my encrypted message from .txt file as cypherText. But I can't find where and how to use the other part that I wrote to the database. How do I add the publicKeyText variable to the process and what parameter do I give to the **`ImportParameters(????);`** field? And also when I set the **`ImportParameters(_privateKey);`** it gives an error:The length of the data to decrypt is not valid for the size of this key.

Comment: "Firstly I encrypted a message with RSA algorithm in C#." - I'd recommend against this; usually you'd use RSA to encrypt/decrypt a symmetric key which then in turns is used to encrypt/decrypt the data (since most symmetric key algos are perfectly suited for arbitrary input length, unlike RSA).

Comment: In the first snippet it looks as if the encryption is done with the own public key and not with the recipient's public key. If this is true, the recipient cannot decrypt the ciphertext, of course. With RSA, both sides exchange the public keys. The encryption is performed with the recipient's public key, who can decrypt with their private key.

Comment: So you named both the encoding and the decoding of the public key `GetPublicKey` while you need a private key... Uh, yeah, you need to fix that.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thx, this clue is helped me. I explain my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I realized that I have to write the private key to the database, not the public key. Therefore, I changed the `GetPublicKey` method in form app which encryped the message as follows.

```
public string GetPrivateKey()
    {
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));

        xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, _privateKey);
        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
```

Then, I got the `privateKey` from database and deserialize it like below.

```
    private string GetPrivateKey(string companyCode) => _companyService.GetCompanyLicenceKey(companyCode);

    private RSAParameters DeserializeXml(string xmlPrivateKey)
    {
        XmlSerializer keySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlPrivateKey);
        XmlReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader);
        RSAParameters privateKey = (RSAParameters)keySerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        return privateKey;
    }
```

So, with this way I reach the `RSAParameters`.Finally I use this key in the `Deserialize` method.

```
  public string Decrypt(string cypherText, string companyCode)
        {
            using (cryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                var dataBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cypherText);
                var privateKeyXml = GetPrivateKey(companyCode);
                var privateKey = DeserializeXml(privateKeyXml);
                cryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters(privateKey);

                var plainText = cryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(dataBytes, false);
                return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plainText);
            }
        }
```